# In Freezed is it possible to create union cases from already existing freezed dataclasses

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dartz

I am using the [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) package to create my json parsers and data classes. As of now I am using [dartz](https://pub.dev/packages/dartz)'s package to create Union cases and handle them in Flutter widgets. For example some of my Union classes looks like the following.

```dart
Either<ApiFailure,ModelA> apiResult1;
Either<ApiFailure,ModelB> apiResult2;
```

and I use them in my flutter widget's builder by folding them and returning specific widget for each cases. For example.

```dart
return apiResul1.fold<Widget>(
  (left) => ErrorWidget(),
  (right) => SuccessWidget(),
);
```

I created `ApiFailure`, `ModelA`, and `ModelB` as data classes using the freezed package. I understood freezed comes with a similar Union class support like dartz where we can define union cases. So I tried using them as follows and based on my initial understanding it is not possible to achieve the following using the already existing data classes for eg. `ModelA and`ApiFailure`.

```dart
@freezed
abstract class ApiResult1 with _$ApiResult1{
  const factory ApiResult1.modelA() =  ModelA;
  const factory ApiResult1.apiFailure() =  ApiFailure;
}

@freezed
abstract class ApiResult2 with _$ApiResult1{
  const factory ApiResult2.modelB() =  ModelB;
  const factory ApiResult2.apiFailure() =  ApiFailure;
}
```

Notice that in the above two union classes I am redefining `ApiFailure` in `ApiResult2` which is what I am trying to Avoid.

**Question**: Is it possible to utilize existing dataclasses to build a union class so that I don't have to make multiple changes just to change the structure of `ApiFailure` object. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.

My usecase is the following:

I have two freezed classes representing failures:
"Feature1Failure", 
"Feature2Failure".

I would like to create a FeaturesFailure union class reusing the two existing one.

Comment: Sorry I got a reply in twitter. According to the [tweet](https://twitter.com/scabhilash/status/1289331998381584384?s=20) from @remi this is not possible with freezed as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use your data classes as parameters?

```
@freezed
abstract class ApiResult1 with _$ApiResult1 {
  const factory ApiResult1.model(ModelA model) = _ModelA;
  const factory ApiResult1.failure(ApiFailure failure) = _ApiFailure1;
}

@freezed
abstract class ApiResult2 with _$ApiResult2 {
  const factory ApiResult2.model(ModelB model) = _ModelB;
  const factory ApiResult2.failure(ApiFailure failure) = _ApiFailure2;
}
```

Then you can do

```
  return apiResult1.when(
    model: (model) => SuccessWidget(),
    failure: (failure) => ErrorWidget(),
  );
```